# Can iPhone USB Hotspot be shared through a MacBook Pro?

Tags: sharing, internet, tethering

My iPhone wireless hotspot quit working, but I can still use the internet through a USB connection. I’m wondering if I can use internet sharing on a MacBook Pro to share the USB internet connection from my phone. I attempted this and found the shared connection on my Apple TV. It connected but didn’t seem to provide internet to the Apple TV. I have another device I would like to use this shared connection with but I have to buy a WiFi adapter to test it. Prior to buying that, I thought someone here may be able to answer if this is even possible.

Comment: Have you tried resetting network settings in Settings > General > Reset > Reset Network Settings.

Comment: Can we assume you are running macos 10.13 high sierra?

Comment: Yep, 10.13.3. Not a beta version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is possible using *System Preferences > Sharing > Internet Sharing*.

Cell Network > iPhone > USB > MacBook Pro > Wi-Fi > other devices

In fact, you have to do it this way as the Wi-Fi on your MBP can either join or create a Wi-Fi network, it cannot do both at the same time.

Also, you should check usage terms of your mobile data provider to see if they allow sharing of personal hotspot in this way - some do not.

Comment: I'm not sure why it wasn't working for me, but I finally got it to go. I was able to connect my Synology NAS directly to my MacBook Pro via ethernet and share my phone connection to it. Didn't have to buy anything :D